# append element don't show up on submit

Tags: javascript

I made an object in javascript that append a table with 5 elements. However when I submit the form the added fields don't show up.

```
var whenCellOne = firstRow.insertCell(1);
this.often = document.createElement("select");
this.often.name = "['"+me.id+"']['often']";
this.often.appendChild(this.createOption("Vecka", "0"));
this.often.appendChild(this.createOption("Månad", "1"));
this.often.onchange = function(){ me.update(); };
whenCellOne.appendChild(this.often);
```

That's how I create one of the elements, I expect it comming up as `$_POST['1a']['often'] = "0"` but the var_dump just looks like this `array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(2) "ok" }` what's wrong? and how do I fix it?

Here is the full javascript code http://pastebin.com/Jai3gChv, and here is the test page http://pastebin.com/F3rgBumh

Comment: what is "this", post more code. explain more

Comment: can you inspect the form to see whether the select element is added to it

Comment: @Legends "this" and "me" refers to the JavaScript object, I added pastebin links to the whole code. I append a few elements into a div inside a form, and when I hit submit those input elements don't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will not populate `$_POST` with data from fields with names of the form `[something]`. You need to change the name.

If you want `$_POST['1a']['often']` to have a value then you need `name="1a[often]"`.

Assuming the value of `me.id` is `1a`, you are currently setting it to `name="['1a']['often']"`

```
this.often.name = "['"+me.id+"']['often']";
```

should be

```
this.often.name = me.id + "[often]";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have also a couple of errors in your script, you have to still implement the bug fixes mentioned by Quentin:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./system/advancedDate.js"></script>
        </head> 
        <body>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div id='1a'></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ok">
            </form>
        </body>
        <footer>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              window.onload = function(){
                var ad = new advancedDate("1a");
                ad.appendInElement();
              }
            </script>
        </footer>
</html>





function advancedDate(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.createDOMElements();
}

advancedDate.prototype.createDOMElements = function(){
    var me = this;
    this.table = document.createElement("table");
    this.table.style.border = "Solid black 3px";

    //Create row 1
    var firstRow = this.table.insertRow(0);
    var secondRow = this.table.insertRow(1);
    var thirdRow = this.table.insertRow(2);
    var fourthRow = this.table.insertRow(3);

    var whenCellOne = firstRow.insertCell(0);
    this.repeat = document.createElement("select");
    this.repeat.name = "['"+me.id+"']['repeat']";
    this.repeat.appendChild(this.createOption("Varje", "0"));
    this.repeat.appendChild(this.createOption("Kommande", "1"));
    whenCellOne.appendChild(this.repeat);

     whenCellOne = firstRow.insertCell(1);
    this.often = document.createElement("select");
    this.often.name = "["+me.id+"][often]";
    this.often.appendChild(this.createOption("Vecka", "0"));
    this.often.appendChild(this.createOption("Månad", "1"));
    this.often.onchange = function(){ me.update(); };
    whenCellOne.appendChild(this.often);

    secondRow.insertCell(0);
    var dateCell = secondRow.insertCell(1);
    this.when = document.createElement("select");
    this.when.name = "['"+me.id+"']['when']";
    this.when.setAttribute("multiple","true");
    this.when.style.width = "300px";
    dateCell.appendChild(this.when);

    var dayCell = thirdRow.insertCell(0);
    dayCell.innerHTML = "Day:";

    var dayInputCell = thirdRow.insertCell(1);
    this.dayInput = document.createElement("input");
    this.dayInput.name = "['"+me.id+"']['when']";
    this.dayInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    this.dayInput.onkeyup = function(){ me.update(); };
    this.dayInput.onblur = function(){ me.update(); };
    dayInputCell.appendChild(this.dayInput);

    var workCell = fourthRow.insertCell(0);
    workCell.innerHTML = "Arbetstid:";

    var workTimeInputCell = fourthRow.insertCell(1);
    this.workTimeInput = document.createElement("input");
    this.workTimeInput.name = "['"+me.id+"']['workTime']";
    this.workTimeInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    this.workTimeInput.onkeyup = function(){ me.calculateTime(this); };
    this.workTimeInput.onblur = function(){ me.calculateTime(this); };
    workTimeInputCell.appendChild(this.workTimeInput);

    this.update();
};

advancedDate.prototype.createOption = function(text, value){
    var e = document.createElement("option");
    e.setAttribute("value",value);
    e.innerHTML = text;
    return e;
};

advancedDate.prototype.calculateTime = function(element){
    var pattern = /([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})([^0-9]+)([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/g;
    if(element.value.match(pattern)){
        var result = pattern.exec(element.value);
        var time1 = (parseInt(result[1]) * 3600) + (parseInt(result[2]) * 60);
        var time2 = (parseInt(result[4]) * 3600) + (parseInt(result[5]) * 60);

        var max = Math.max(time1, time2);
        var min = Math.min(time1, time2);
        var time = max-min;

        element.value = Number((time/3600).toFixed(2));
    }
};

advancedDate.prototype.update = function(){

    var currentDay;

    try{
        currentDay = parseInt(this.dayInput.value);
    }catch(err){
        currentDay = -1;
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = parseInt(d.getFullYear())+1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var months = [
        ["01, Januari",     "January",      0],
        ["02, Februari",    "February",     1],
        ["03, Mars",        "March",        2],
        ["04, April",       "April",        3],
        ["05, Maj",         "May",          4],
        ["06, Juni",        "June",         5],
        ["07, Juli",        "July",         6],
        ["08, Augusti",     "August",       7],
        ["09, September",   "September",    8],
        ["10, Oktober",     "October",      9],
        ["11, November",    "November",     10],
        ["12, December",    "December",     11]];

    var weeks = [
        ["Måndag",  "Monday"    ],
        ["Tisdag",  "Tuesday"   ],
        ["Onsdag",  "Wednesday" ],
        ["Torsdag", "Thursday"  ],
        ["Fredag",  "Friday"    ],
        ["Lördag",  "Saturday"  ],
        ["Söndag",  "Sunday"    ]];


    //Save the selected values
    var selected = [];
    try{
        for(var i=0; i<this.when.options.length; i++){
            if(this.when.options[i].selected)
                selected.push(this.when.options[i].value);
        }
    }catch(err){

    }

    if(this.often.value === "0"){
        this.when.options.length = 0;
        for(var x=0; x<weeks.length; x++)
            this.when.appendChild(this.createOption(weeks[x][0], weeks[x][1]));
        //Make extra invisable
        this.table.rows[2].style.display = 'none';
        this.dayInput.value = "";
    }

    if(this.often.value === "1"){
        this.when.options.length = 0;
        for(var y=0; y<months.length; y++)
            this.when.appendChild(
                this.createOption(
                    ((month > months[y][2] || (month === months[y][2] && currentDay < day)) ? year+ "-" : "") + months[y][0], months[y][1]));
        this.table.rows[2].style.display = 'table-row';
    }

    //Load selected again
    for(var z=0; z<this.when.options.length; z++){
        for(var j=0; j<selected.length; j++){
            if(this.when.options[z].value === selected[j]){
                this.when.options[z].selected="selected"; break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Dynamic height
    this.when.size = this.when.options.length;
};

advancedDate.prototype.appendInElement = function(){
    var e = document.getElementById(this.id);
    e.appendChild(this.table);
};
```

Comment: Why change the loop variables names? they all work fine with var i, since i is just used in their own individual loop.

Comment: It works, but you should not declare variables repeatedly in your code as they were declared already, actually you have to remove the var in your consecutive loops, when the variable, i.e. "i" is already declared.

Comment: I'm so used to other programming languages, which don't keep the variable after a for loop. But I think I will just declare the i variable before the first for loop, and then set it to 0 without re-declaring it. Since i is just for the loop, that should cause any issues, right?

Comment: you have to take care of course, but if you reset "i" every time before you use it, then it's ok ;-)
So yes, you can do it, just declare it once only